# SQL Server query for a user with different data in the one column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains columns `Users`, `UserGroupID` and `Paydate`.

The `UserGroupID` defaults to 1 or 2 on initial signup but some users over time will be updated to a `UserGroupID` of 3.

A single user will be the table many times as it records the paydates for users.

How can I query the database to find a user who is now 3 and also view what their previous `UserGroupID` was?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a second table to track history. It can hold UserId, UserGroupID, and the date the change happened. Use a stored procedure to handle updates. This procedure adds a row to the history table any time the UserGroupID is updated.

You query is something like:

```
Declare @UserId varchar(30) = 'My UserId'
Select UserId, UserGroupId from Users where UserId = @UserId
Union All
Select UserId, UserGroupId from UserHistory where UserId = @UserId
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

That could work going forward but I'm working with a lot of data already in a table.

Comment: I am not sure there is a way great way to get your history. You could try taking snapshots from backups and attempt to construct the history, but that could be a long shot. Do you have another table that may have an audit trail that you can use to populate historical data? For example, a table that you know was updated by a specific user where the only a specific UserGroupID has privileges to insert.